# jenkins workspace dir issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline has been work all good until today. 
Jenkins dynamically spins up a slave container (docker cloud) where all my steps are run from. Error as below, just wondering why jenkins create a tmp dir in the workspace dir.

```
[Pipeline] sh
[xxx_root_proj] Running shell script
+ cd ./xxx_root_proj
/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_root_proj@tmp/durable-b532c37c/script.sh: 3: cd: can't cd to ./xxx_root_proj
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
Finished: FAILURE
```

Just wondering if anyone has come across this before. 
I think the "/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_root_proj@tmp" is the problem, not sure how jenkins uses this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

@tmp folder is created by Jenkins in workspace for shared library components etc. Basically a temp working dir for the pipeline